# Decoding base64 content from Github API

Tags: python, github, google-cloud-platform, web2py, github-api

Hi I'm currently trying to decode the base64 returned from the Github API `/:username/:repo/contents/:filepath`

which returns a json object

> `{
>    "type": "file",
>    "encoding": "base64",
>    "size": 5362,
>    "name": "README.md",
>    "path": "README.md",
>    "content": "encoded content ...",
>    "sha": "3d21ec53a331a6f037a91c368710b99387d012c1",
>    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/contents/README.md",
>    "git_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/git/blobs/3d21ec53a331a6>f037a91c368710b99387d012c1",
>    "html_url": >"https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/blob/master/README.md",
>    "download_url": >"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/octokit/octokit.rb/master/README.md",
>    "_links": {
>      "git": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/git/blobs/3d21ec53a331a6f037a91c368710b99387d012c1",
>      "self": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/contents/README.md",
>       "html": "https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/blob/master/README.md"
>     }`
>   }

The content is encoded as base64, but when I try to decode it - it gives me random characters

`from googleapiclient import discovery
from goйɽ́Ё!ɽ)ɽwWF&6ƖVB6W'f6U66VB'B6W'f6T66[ܙY[X[[\ܝX]QgTS_DISCOVERY_URL='https://sheets.googleapis.c͍ٕɕٕͥМ)M.....`

here is my code:

> ```
>    try:
>        result = urlfetch.fetch(url, headers={"accept": >"application/vnd.github.v3+json"})
>        if result.status_code == 200:
>            decoded_content = base64.b64decode(result.content)
>            print(decoded_content)
>         else:
>                    self.response.status_code = result.status_code
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parse the json response with `json.loads(result.content)` and get the `content` field afterwards :

```
import base64
import urlfetch
import json

result = urlfetch.fetch(
    "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/contents/README.md", 
    headers={"accept": "application/vnd.github.v3+json"})

if result.status_code == 200:
    data = json.loads(result.content)
    decoded_content = base64.b64decode(data["content"])
    print(decoded_content)
else:
    print(result.status_code)
```

You can test it [here](https://repl.it/@bertrandmartel/fetchGithubContent)